# regex exclude dash/hyphen if there no number found afterward

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm tried to extract number between a hyphen, it works but when the number after hyphen is not found and leaving with whitespace it will take the hyphen into the match.

Here the code what I tried with:

```
$join = '';
if (preg_match('/(?<=book)[\s\d]+-?[\s\d]+/i', $find, $matches)) {
    if (strpos($matches[0], ' ') && strpos($matches[0], '-')) {
        $remove_whitespace = str_replace(' ', '', $matches[0]);
        $join.= 'b' . $remove_whitespace;
    }
    else {
        $remove_whitespace = str_replace(' ', '', $matches[0]);
        $join.= 'b' . $remove_whitespace;
    }
    echo $join;
}
```

What I expected:

1. "Book 1 - abcd" = "Book 1"
2. "Book 1 - " = "Book 1"
3. "Book 1 - 2" = "Book 1-2"

The actual output:

1. "Book 1 - abcd" = "Book 1-" (had hyphen with it)
2. "Book 1 - " = "Book 1-" (had hyphen with it)
3. "Book 1 - 2" = "Book 1-2"

Comment: `Book\s*\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/wUxfuK/1)) or `Book\s*\K\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?`?

Comment: the second one is what I expected, it working. I will accept your answer if you create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~Book\s*\K\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wUxfuK/2)

**Details**

- `Book` -  a literal string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?` - an optional sequence of a `-` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces (`\s*-\s*`) and then 1+ digits.